# Is this piecewise function Riemann Integrable?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, functions, definite-integrals

Is $f(x)$ where,

$
   f(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       \frac{1}{x^2} & : x <0\\
       x & : x \geq0
     \end{array}
   \right.
$,

Riemann Integrable over $[-1,1]$?  Looking at the graph it doesn't seem like it possibly could be.  I can't quite convince myself, however.

Comment: Just for completeness: the improper Riemann integral also does not exist. (Supplementing Julián's answer.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not bounded, so it is not Riemann integrable.